# Error parsing JSON Object from PHP web service

Tags: java, php, android, json

I seem to be getting an incomplete JSON object from my PHP web service. My PHP codes are as follows:

```
<?php
define('IEM_PATH', '../admin/com');
require_once('../admin/includes/config.php');
require_once('../admin/com/lib/IEM.class.php');
require_once ('../admin/com/lib/IEM/DBFACTORY.class.php');
require_once ('../admin/com/lib/IEM/baseAPI.class.php');
require_once ('../admin/com/lib/API/USERS.class.php');
require_once ('../admin/com/lib/IEM/baseRecord.class.php');
require_once ('../admin/com/lib/record/Users.class.php');

    function GetLists($userid = 0, $getUnconfirmedCount = false) {

        $userid = $_REQUEST['userID'];
        if (!$userid) {
        trigger_error('User object has no user id as parameter.', E_USER_NOTICE);
            return false;
        }


        if (!$userid) {
            $userid = $this->userid;
        }

        require_once('../admin/functions/api/lists.php');

        $listapi = new Lists_API();
        $returnA =  $listapi->GetListByUserID($userid, $getUnconfirmedCount);
        $returnResult1 = array();
            foreach ($returnA as $key => $value) { 
                //$lists[] = $key;
                $returnResult["contactList"][] = array("listID" => $returnA[$key]['listid'], "name" => $returnA[$key]['name']);
            }
       $returnResult["success"] = 1;
       echo json_encode($returnResult);
    }
    GetLists();
```

However when I try to retrieve the results my logcat only shows:

```
E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for success
```

By doing a logging, my android returns my JSON object as follows

```
D/Returned JSON: {"androidid":"1"}
```

from these codes

```
// getting JSON response from PHP web service
JSONObject returnedJSONObj = listsJSONParser.makeHttpRequest(Constant.URL
                    + "RetrieveList.php", "GET", params);

Log.d("Returned JSON ", String.valueOf(returnedJSONObj));

success = returnedJSONObj.getInt("success");
```

I don't understand why there is no value for success when my PHP does return a JSON Array as well as the success value according to the code, but the android studio java codes does not detect these values in the JSON object. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that you are sending the request to the correct PHP script? It does not match to the logged JSON object.

Comment: Without running your code, I am not able to get actual error. But still you can try by adding `exit` statement after `echo json_encode` statement.

Comment: I think your code need correction for `getInt("success")`. use `androidid` instade.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd my main problem is not the getInt part though, it's the returned JSON object, it should have attributes `success` and `contactList`

Answer (score 1):

you should modify your android code

```
success = returnedJSONObj.getInt("success");
```

to

```
success = returnedJSONObj.getInt("androidid");
```

Comment: if i do that then i'll get No value for contactList, contactList is one of the attributes that should be retrieved in the JSON object also but it's not.

Comment: according to your Log your Json is  {"androidid":"1"} which doesn't have contactList details.either you are calling wrong URL or something wrong with your php file .please check your PHP file and make sure it is generating correct json

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a problem with your php file, so instead of returning a JSON object, it returns a string with the error. 
You need to make sure you are sending the correct POST or GET values to the URL if you are or you check for database errors. try logging the inputstream coming from the php server to see the full error it is sending